# Puppet facter - How to fix Error: Could not retrieve fact='os', resolution='<anonymous>'

Tags: puppet, facter

On my windows server machine, just `facter` command gives the following error-

```
[stdout][0;36mDebug: Loading facts from C:/ProgramData/.../facter/windows_version.rb[0m
[stderr]Could not retrieve fact='os', resolution='<anonymous>': failed to parse display name of moniker `winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/cimv2'
[stderr] HRESULT error code:0x80010114
[stderr] The requested object does not exist.
[stderr]Could not retrieve fact='os', resolution='<anonymous>': failed to parse display name of moniker `winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/cimv2'
[stderr] HRESULT error code:0x80010114
[stderr] The requested object does not exist.
[stderr]Could not retrieve fact='os', resolution='<anonymous>': failed to parse display name of moniker `winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/cimv2'
[stderr] HRESULT error code:0x80010114
[stderr] The requested object does not exist.
[stderr]Could not retrieve fact='virtual', resolution='<anonymous>': failed to parse display name of moniker `winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/cimv2'
[stderr] HRESULT error code:0x80010108
```

This is happening suddenly, 2 weeks ago it was working fine.
Any idea how to fix this and what is causing these errors? Due to this, some Ruby scripts are failing.